# connecting javaBean and JESS

Tags: java, jess

I just cant find the solution...
heres the prob:
I have a simple main class, where i change the properties of a jvaBean. Then I want to load the properties of the javaBean as facts into my JESS program.

I make it simple:
//the java main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Bean testbean = new Bean();
testbean.setName("test");
Rete engine = new Rete();
engine.batch("simple");
engine.run();
}
```

//the Bean class

```
public String name;
public String getName(){return name;}
public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
```

//the JESS simple.clp

```
(defclass bean Bean)
(bind ?b (new Bean))
(definstance bean ?b)
(facts)
```

When i start the java main the fact of the javaBean istn`t asserted. The output (facts) shows that name is still nil (null)

can someone help me please  thanks a lot!!

Danny

Answer (score 0):

You create two `Bean` objects here; one from Java code, and one from Jess code. You set the `name` property of the one created from Java, but it's the one created from Jess that actually gets added to working memory. You could do this either in Jess or in Java or in a combination of the two, but if you want just one object, you need to create just one. For example, you might do it all from Java like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bean testbean = new Bean();
    testbean.setName("test");
    Rete engine = new Rete();
    engine.defclass("bean", "Bean", null, false);
    engine.definstance("bean", testbean, false);
    engine.eval("(facts)");
 }
```